# what is the correct method for upgrading an extension on a live site after pulling its updated code from a development site?

Tags: extension, developer

We use a development site and github.com repository, and then pull from github.com down to our live site.

So when upgrading our extensions we update the code on our dev site, test it's all ok, then push it to github.com, ready to pull it down to our live site.

What's the correct thing to do on the live site in this case? Disable the extension before downloading the code and then re-enable it? Or what?

Apologies if my searching missed this in an obvious part of the documentation or elsewhere.

We're on Civi 4.7.27 and Drupal 7.56

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do is:

1. if the upgrade is on my extensions page within the UI then I try
   upgrading from the UI (obvioulsy on test first as you mention).
2. if there is no upgrade on my extension page, I tend to download a
   release rather than link the production site directly to the master
   branch on GitHub. I tend to do that only in test. I am sure there
   are pros and cons for pulling directly but this is what I do.
3. if the extension is a tiny one and I know for a fact the impact is
   minimal I replace the extension directory with the extracted new release without disabling first.
4. if I know the extension is a bit bigger I will disable first, then extract and replace the extension directory and enable again.

Comment: aha... that's really helpful in terms of what to do on the dev site - if I'm understanding correctly. But then, I'm wondering what to then do on the live site after pushing the new code to the live site. I can't use the upgrade button on the live site without causing a git conflict. (as far as my rather limited understanding of git goes :-)  )

Comment: That is probably right. If I was using git on live I would probably disable and then pull. But be careful I was pulling the correct release/commit